# motherboard selection for VMware ESX or Xen

Tags: linux, networking, hardware, vmware-esxi

any motherboards using compatile NIC chipsets for VMware ESXi4.1 or Xen 3.4?

all major manufacturers ASUS, MSI, Gigabyte seem to be using either Realtek or VIA based chips for NIC which so not have drivers support....

I am considering SOHO borads based on AMD800 series or Intel P55, X58 series

only Intel chipsets have broad support e1000* drivers (825*)

please suggest.....thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably the safest way to go before buying anything:

[VMWare Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?ie=UTF-8&q=hardware%20compatability%20vmware)

I got so annoyed with being forced to use certain types of hardware for VMWare I opted for KVM (KVM needs CPU extensions to run) and OpenVZ (it's very fast and needs no specific hardware but doesn't like MS "VMs").

Comment: thanks, have been through the HCL before this post, some Intel boards seem to have 82578DC chips for onboard NIC. My problem is unable to find a intel based add-on NIC card

Comment: No problem. If it's of help we use these PCI cards for the best throughput (up to 18 months ago) for about £100/card: 82575EB, 82576 (ET Dual Port Server Adapter) which use the "igb" driver (which is the most modern) and the 82573E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) which uses the "e1000" driver. HTH, JR.

Comment: Sorry, I should say these NICs were **NOT** picked to be VMWare compatible but rather for the best throughput afforded. HTH, JR